# Java 2D: Moving a point P a certain distance closer to another point?

Tags: java, java-2d

What is the best way to go about moving a Point2D.Double x distance closer to another Point2D.Double?

Edit: Tried to edit, but so went down for maintenance. No this is not homework

I need to move a plane (A) towards the end of a runway (C) and point it in the correct direction (angle a).

[alt text http://img246.imageshack.us/img246/9707/planec.png](http://img246.imageshack.us/img246/9707/planec.png)

Here is what I have so far, but it seems messy, what is the usual way to go about doing something like this?

```
    //coordinate = plane coordinate (Point2D.Double)
    //Distance = max distance the plane can travel in this frame

    Triangle triangle = new Triangle(coordinate, new Coordinate(coordinate.x, landingCoordinate.y),  landingCoordinate);

    double angle = 0;

    //Above to the left
    if (coordinate.x <= landingCoordinate.x && coordinate.y <= landingCoordinate.y)
    {
        angle = triangle.getAngleC();
        coordinate.rotate(angle, distance);
        angle = (Math.PI-angle);
    }
    //Above to the right
    else if (coordinate.x >= landingCoordinate.x && coordinate.y <= landingCoordinate.y)
    {
        angle = triangle.getAngleC();
        coordinate.rotate(Math.PI-angle, distance);
        angle = (Math.PI*1.5-angle);
    }

    plane.setAngle(angle);
```

The triangle class can be found at http://pastebin.com/RtCB2kSZ

Bearing in mind the plane can be in in any position around the runway point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Vectors to the rescue!*

Given points A and B. Create a vector V from A to B (by doing B-A). Normalize vector V into a unit vector and then just multiply it with the distance, d, you want and finally add the resulting vector to point A. ie:

```
  A_moved = A + |(B-A)|*d
```

Java(ish)

```
  Vector2D a_moved = a.add(b.subtract(a).norm().multiply(d));
```

No angles, no nasty trig needed.

Answer (score 6):

The shortest distance between two points is a line, so simply move that point `x` units along the line that connects the two points.

---

**Edit:** I didn't want to give away the specifics of the answer if this is homework, but this is simple enough that it can be illustrated without being too spoiler-y.

Let us assume you have two points `A` = (x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>) and `B` = (x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>). The line that includes these two points has the equation

> (x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>) + t · (x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>)

where `t` is some parameter. Notice that when `t = 1`, the point specified by the line is `B`, and when `t = 0`, the point specified by the line is `A`.

Now, you would like to move `B` to `B'`, a point which is a new distance `d` away from `A`:

```
 A                       B'            B
(+)---------------------(+)-----------(+)

 <========={ d }=========>
```

The point `B'`, like any other point on the line, is also governed by the equation we showed earlier. But what value of `t` do we use? Well, when `t` is 1, the equation points to `B`, which is `|AB|` units away from `A`. So the value of `t` that specifies `B'` is `t` = `d/|AB|`.

Solving for |AB| and plugging this into the above equation is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 6):

You can minimize the difference along both axis by a percent (that depends on how much you want to move the points).

For example:

```
Point2D.Double p1, p2;
//p1 and p2 inits

// you don't use abs value and use the still point as the first one of the subtraction
double deltaX = p2.getX() - p1.getX();
double deltaY = p2.getY() - p1.getY();

// now you know how much far they are
double coeff = 0.5; //this coefficient can be tweaked to decice how much near the two points will be after the update.. 0.5 = 50% of the previous distance

p1.setLocation(p1.getX() + coeff*deltaX, p1.getY() + coeff*deltaY);
```

So you moved `p1` halfway toward `p2`. The good thing avoid `abs` is that, if you choose which point will be moved and which one will stand still you can avoid if tests and just use the raw coefficient.

Comment: @Jack: Notice how your solution does the _exact_ same calculations as mine but using another notation.

Comment: Yeah, because vectors are always the best way to handle things :)

Answer (score 3):

```
double angle = Math.atan2(landingCoordinate.y-coordinate.y, landingCoordinate.x-coordinate.x);

coordinate.x += Math.cos(angle)*distance;
coordinate.y += Math.sin(angle)*distance;

//Add 90 degress to the plane angle
plane.setAngle(angle + 1.57079633);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(point A is to be moved closer to B)

if (A.x > B.x)
    //decrement A.x
if (A.x < B.x)
    //increment A.x
```

that might be the basic idea in pseudocode, but there's a lot more to it than that. How do you define 'best' way?

Certain things need to be considered:

- Is there a specific measure/ratio you want the points to be apart from each other, or do you just want them closer?
- Should both coordinates always be modified? (e.g. if you want to move (1,50) closer to (0,0), do you make it (.5, 25) or just (1,25)?
- if the point is to be 1 unit away, should it be 1 unit horizontally? directly diagonally? 1 unit away on the line between the 2 points?

Give us a little more detail and we'll see what we've got. :D

Answer (score 0):

In this [game](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/), integral coordinates are used to represent squares in a grid. The method [`move(int row, int col)`](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/org/gcs/robot/RCModel.html#move%28int,%20int%29) moves toward the specified row and column by advancing one square in one of eight semi-cardinal directions, as seen [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/robotchase/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/org/gcs/robot/RCModel.java#l238).